# Cancel an onBlur event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to set up an **onBlur** event for an **input** element that validates the value and, if invalid, "cancels" the blur and refocusses the input.  However returning false from **onBlur** does not cancel the **onBlur** the way it does with **onClick**.  Is there a solution for this (perhaps using jQuery?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of any reliable cross-browser way to do this. Usually setting a small timeout in the `onblur` event and calling `focus()` when the timer fires works.

For example:

```
document.getElementById('your_input_id').onblur = function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() { self.focus(); }, 10);
}
```

Comment: How can I pass the DOM element to the timeout handler?  setTimeout only takes a code string, not an object

Comment: @JoelFan: You can pass a function to `setTimeout`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Actually, `setTimeout` takes a function.  `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 40);`

Comment: Very cool, thanks!  Even a timeout of 0 works.  (I guess you just have to schedule an event rather than trying to do the work inside the running event handler)

Comment: @JoelFan: Yes, that's true. I just gave 10 as an example because in reality, a 0 timeout still defaults to a minimum of 10 or 15.

Comment: This was extremely helpful.  I needed to do something on blur all the time except when click on a specific button.  The timeout cedes control to the other events.  In my case, I was removing the element (which canceled even the timeout), but you could set flags or use some other flow control - AWESOME!

Answer (score 4):

You can call `focus()` in the handler.
This will sometimes help.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by using jQuery's `focus()` function inside a zero-second timeout. Here's an example:

```
$('#my_input').bind('blur', function(event) {
   var $input = $(this);
   var is_input_valid = false;

   // Code to determine if input is valid
   // ...

   if (!is_input_valid) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $input.focus();
      }, 0);
      return false;
   }

});
```

Comment: that works but the disadvantage is that it only works for elements that have an "id" tag, and then only if that "id" is guaranteed to be unique on the page

Comment: Good point. If you need to use something other than an ID, then you could assign `this` to `var self` and use self within the timeout callback closure.

Comment: The "safest" zero-second timeout you can use is actually about 16ms. This is due to differences in JavaScript timers on various devices / browsers. If you use 0 for a zero-second timeout, you will find that your code is synchronous, sometimes.

Comment: @Niek Do you have a source for that? According to MDN <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting> browsers have a minimum delay which is enforced.

Comment: @cpburnz I'm afraid not. That text was provided as an edit on the answer by an anonymous user.