# knockout data-bind value incorrect when adding new row dynamically

Tags: knockout.js

My program:

I have a table of data which is an observable array of observables.

- When tabbing out of the last input of the last row it adds a new row of empty inputs. The focus is set in the first input of the new row.
- User types in an item number; when they tab out it does some checks on that item number and based on whether it passes those checks

  1. it goes on to the next field
  2. it goes back to that input and gives a message stating invalid input and selects the text.

That all works fine.  So the user goes through and enters all valid data in that row and then tabs out of the last input and it adds a new row.  **But it is not setting the focus to the first input and I can't even click in there,** I assume because that `hasFocus`/`invalidItem` variable is set to false.  I'm not sure how to set that back to true when adding a new line.

Here is my relevant HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div data-bind="if: (itemNo.length < 1)"><input data-bind="value: itemNo, hasFocus: $parent.invalidItem, selected: $parent.invalidItem, event: { blur: $parent.checkItemNo }, attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].itemNo', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__itemNo' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" class="form-control item-id" /></div>
```

And here is my relevant Knockout:

```
var itemModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.itemNo = ko.observable(data ? data.itemNo : undefined).extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Item no. required."
            }
        });
        self.brocCode = ko.observable(data ? data.brocCode : undefined).extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Bro code required."
            }
        });
        self.itemDesc = ko.observable(data ? data.itemDesc : undefined).extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Item desc required."
            }
        });
        self.retail = ko.observable(data ? data.retail : undefined).extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Retail required."
            }
        });
        self.prizeNum = ko.observable(data ? data.prizeNum : undefined).extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Prize num required."
            }
        });
        self.itemOrder = ko.observable(data ? data.itemOrder : undefined).extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Item order required."
            }
        });
    }
var itemsModel = function(items) {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray(items);

        self.invalidItem = ko.observable(true);
        console.log("focus has been set");

        self.checkItemNo = function(data) {
            console.log("lost focus - " + self.invalidItem());
            var itemNo = $.trim(data.itemNo());

            if (itemNo != "") {
                var item = "";
                $.each(window.listOfItems, function(i, v) {
                    if (v.No.search(itemNo) != -1) {
                        item = v.Description;
                        return;
                    }
                });
                if(item != "") {
                    var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function(newItem) {
                        return itemNo === newItem.itemNo;
                    });
                    console.log("match: " + match);
                    if (!match) {
                        data.itemDesc(item);
                    } else { // item already entered
                        setTimeout(function() { self.invalidItem(true); }, 1);
                        slideDownMsg("Item already entered.");
                        slideUpMsg(3000);
                    }
                } else { // invalid item #
                    setTimeout(function() { self.invalidItem(true); }, 1);
                    slideDownMsg("Invalid item number.");
                    slideUpMsg(3000);
                }
            }
        }        

        self.submit = function() {
            //self.showErrors(true);
            if (viewModel.errors().length === 0) {
                console.log('Thank you.');
                $("#brochureForm").submit();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Please check your submission.');
                viewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
                $(".input-validation-error").first().focus();
            }
        }

        self.addLine = function() {
            self.invalidItem(true);
            console.log(self.invalidItem());
            self.items.push( new itemModel() );
            //setTimeout(function() { self.invalidItem(true); }, 1);
        };
```

**Updated**

OK, I got my fiddle to work like my local code now.  Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tLfezuu1/8/
So when the user tabs out of the last input it adds a new row of blank inputs.  User types in a number in first input and hits tab.  It runs some checks on that number and either sends focus to next input if checks passed or sends focus back to that input highlighting the text if checks failed.

Comment: Would help if you could post a snippet that runs or a fiddle. There are some things that worry me in the code, but it's hard to tell what exactly is causing the issue... (e.g.: Why the `setTimeout`s? Is `itemNo` observable or not? Why the `$().focus()`? Why both a `value` bind and subscribe to `blur`?)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I will work on getting a fiddle.  The timeout is needed as I learned from my last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557273/knockoutjs-hasfocus-implementation-on-dynamically-added-row

Comment: `itemNo` is observable.  Are you talking about this line: `$(".input-validation-error").first().focus();`?

Comment: If `itemNo` is an observable, you should use `itemNo().length`. `itemNo.length` is not what you want.

Comment: I added in my itemModel so you can see the itemNo code.

Comment: If I change it to `itemNo().length`, I get error: `TypeError: itemNo is not a function`

Comment: @user3297291, are you able to help out with the things that worry you?  I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: I'd love to help but I'm not sure I completely understand the intended behavior... When you've filled in a row's last input, what *should* happen that is *not* happening?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated my last paragraph now.

Comment: One important mistake I've spotted checking your latest fiddle: you have to bind the value to the `observable`, not to its initial value. Change `value: itemNo()` to `value: itemNo`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that.  Still it's making that first itemNo input readonly when I tab out of it.  And it's not correctly checking for matches either.

Answer (score 0):

`itemNo` is an observable, so you cannot read it without using `()` unless you pass the observable directly to a binding that unwraps it. Since you don't initialize `itemNo`, it starts off as `undefined`, and you can't read its length anyway. Since `undefined` and an empty string are both falsy, you can just use `ifnot` and `if` with the observable.

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: itemNo">...</div>
<div data-bind="if: itemNo">...</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rwa03vrb/15/

Comment: Problem is, once I type something in itemNo and tab, it switches to the `if: itemNo` version.

Comment: I want all previous entries already loaded to acquire the readonly attr and I want the ones that are dynamically added as new rows to stay editable and have the hasFocus and blur bindings.  It needs to stay as the `ifnot: itemNo` version even after something is typed and blurred.

Comment: Well you've now brought up a completely different issue that's not part of  your original question. I've answered your question. If you update your question, I'll try to answer that as well.